# External table Always insert in a new file, is there any way to write to same file?

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage, sql-insert, external-tables, polybase

I have a external table in SQL Server which points to CSV files in folder of Azure blob storage, I enabled polybase export and trying to insert data using insert query. It works but it always creates new file.

Is there any way I can write to single file or give file name while insert?

Here's my table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE archive.filetransferauditlog (
    [id] [int]  NULL,
    [STATUS] [varchar](10)  NULL,
    [EVENT] [varchar](10)  NULL,
    [fileNameWithPath] [varchar](2048) NULL,
    [eventStartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [eventEndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](4096) NULL,
    [loggedInUserId] [int] NULL,
    [transferType] [int] NULL
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = '/filetransferauditlog/',
    DATA_SOURCE = archivepurgedataExternalDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = ParquetFile
    )
GO
```

Query I am using:

```
Insert into archive.filetransferauditlog
select Top(5)
from dbo.filetransferauditlog
```

Please suggest me any way we can give the file name while insert.

When I try to give location for table  to a single file instead of directory, I am able to run select query but not insert.

It returns below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQLNCLI11". CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'wasbs://demoarchive@testarchivedemo.blob.core.windows.net/filetransferauditlogText/QID5060_20220607_54101_0.txt' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We posted the same question in to Microsoft community and we found answer and the workaround from there.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/external-table-always-insert-in-a-new-file-is-there-any-way-to/m-p/3480998#M1680

Thanks everyone for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that you should execute

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Donnees\\dev\\table_exp.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES STARTING BY 'export-table' TERMINATED BY '$\n'
FROM name_of_table;
```

***Note:*** Into outfile his is the file path
fields terminated by:his is the file path
enclosed by:the symbol that frames the column values
lines starting by this is how your recording in the file will start
TERMINATED BY:with which symbol does your recording end?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQLNCLI11". CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'wasbs://demoarchive@testarchivedemo.blob.core.windows.net/filetransferauditlogText/QID5060_20220607_54101_0.txt' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.
```

As per  [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-errors-and-possible-solutions?view=sql-server-ver16#cannot-execute-the-query-remote-query), ***The reason behind getting this error because of PolyBase external table pointed out repeatedly reads all the files, so column or data may be discrepancy***

- Hope you created the external table first and then use INSERT INTO SELECT to export to the external location. ***While exporting, only data can be exported not a column***

> Please suggest me any way we can give the file name while insert

- If you want data in each table consists in single file, use FILE name in the location section by the directory
- If you want multiple file in table set the files into different directories
- If you want to create a table on top of csv file just use `LOCATION '/warehouse/develop/myfile`
- Make sure you are giving correct path in location attributes are not, give your location along with your file name as below

```sql
Create External Table Your table name
(col1 int)WITH (LOCATION=  '/filetransferauditlog/ your file name' ,DATA_SOURCE); OR
Create External Table  Your table name
(col1 int) WITH (LOCATION = '/filetransferauditlog/ ',DATA_SOURCE);
```

For [inserting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-errors-and-possible-solutions?view=sql-server-ver16#create-table-as-select-error) into same file use ***Join query*** while export please check whether you are using correct format as sample below

```sql
INSERT  INTO dbo.filetransferauditlog 
SELECT T.* FROM Insured_Customers T1 JOIN CarSensor_Data T2 
ON (T1.CustomerKey = T2.CustomerKey)
WHERE T2.YearMeasured = 2009  and T2.Speed > 40;
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[PolyBase query scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-queries?view=sql-server-ver16#export-data)

[PolyBase errors and possible solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-errors-and-possible-solutions?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This is not working, in document they refer to directory and not the single file. they have given /old_data/2009/customerdata which is directory and not file. so it will export the data and create a new file in that directory